# redirect after login with context

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get a login function to redirect to a certain view, but I can't find a way to use a navigate or this.props.push inside the context api. The function that makes the redirection is handleLogin and is consumed from loginForm view.
but if I tried to use useNavigate, I would have to transform that class component to a functional

AppProvider

```
// React
import React from 'react';

// AppContext
import AppContext from '../AppContext';

// Axios
import axios from 'axios';

// React-cookies
import cookies from "js-cookie";

class AppProvider extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      store: {
        userInfo: {},
        isLoggedIn: localStorage.getItem('isLogged') ? true : false
      },
      actions: {
        handleLogin: this.handleLogin
      }
    }

  }

  handleLogin = (e, credentials) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios.post('/users/signin', credentials, {
      'content-type': 'application-json'
    })
    .then((res) => {
      cookies.set('auth-token', res.headers['auth-token']);
      this.setState({store:{isLoggedIn: true}});
      localStorage.setItem('isLogged', true);
      
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default AppProvider;
```

LoginForm:

```
// React
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// Mui
import { Grid, Card, CardContent, TextField, Button, Typography } from '@mui/material';

// React-router
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

// Axios
import axios from 'axios';

// React-cookies
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";

// Context
import AppContext from '../../AppContext';


const LoginForm = () => {

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [ credentials, setCredentials ] = useState({
    email: null,
    password_digest: null
  });

  const [cookies, setCookies] = useCookies(['auth-token']);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setCredentials({...credentials, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  }

  return(
    <AppContext.Consumer>
      {context => {
        console.log(context)
        return(
          <Grid container direction="column" alignItems="center" paddingTop="10%">
            <Grid item xs={3}>
              <Card
              style={{
                background: '#1e272e',
                padding: '1em'
              }}
              >
                <Typography textAlign="center" color="white">
                  Welcome!
                </Typography>
                <CardContent>
                  <form onSubmit={(e) => context.actions.handleLogin(e, credentials)}>
                      <TextField
                        variant='filled'
                        label="email"
                        name="email"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        sx={{
                            display: 'block',
                            margin: '.5rem 0'
                          }}
                          inputProps={{style: {color: 'white'}}}
                          InputLabelProps={{style: {color: 'white'}}}
                      />
                      <TextField 
                        variant="filled"
                        label="password"
                        name="password_digest"
                        type="password"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        rows={4}
                        sx={{
                          display: 'block',
                          margin: '1rem 0'
                        }}
                        inputProps={{style: {color: 'white'}}}
                        InputLabelProps={{style: {color: 'white'}}}
                      />
                      <Button variant='contained' 
                              color='primary'
                              type='submit'>
                          Login
                      </Button>
                  </form>
                  <Link to="/register"><Typography variant="span" style={{fontSize: '.8em'}} mt={2} color="white">Don't you have an account? Sign up</Typography></Link>
                </CardContent>
              </Card>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        )
      }}
    </AppContext.Consumer>
  )
}

export default LoginForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a route config declaring routes and the files each route points to. This will help in letting `react-router` know what view to display when redirected to the respective link.
Refer the [tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial) here for more information.

Comment: Hello, thanks. I have already declared routes config.

Comment: Ok, would be great if you can provide a sandbox of your code.